# Eurostile Font support in iOS?

Tags: ios

I have a requirement for an iPhone application, where the application font should be in 'Eurostile Font'. I have checked the available fonts provided by iOS, it does not have 'Eurostile Font'. Is it possible to import this font to application? If not, is there any equivalent font for 'Eurostile Font' ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The short answer is, no.

The [Wikipedia-page for Eurostile](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eurostile) states that foundries like Linotype and URW have versions of Eurostile. I haven't read their font licenses, but pretty certain they don't allow re-distribution of the font files (without paying them a large amount of money).

If you had a version of Eurostile (or any other font) that you wanted and legally could use, you can do (since iOS version 3.2):

1. Add the font file to the project in Xcode (in Resources for example).
2. Add the key `UIAppFonts` to the `info.plist` file and make it an array type.
3. Add the font file name to the array.
4. Use it by doing, for example, `[UIFont fontWithName:@"Eurostile" size:20]`.

Your options are:

- Pay the foundries for a license of Eurostile that can be re-distributed.
- If you only need a heading or some text on a button, draw the text you want to use and use the bitmap image in your app.
- Find a similar font to Eurostile that is distributed with less restrictions (one such license is the SIL Open Font License). A good place to start looking is the [Google Web Fonts](http://www.google.com/webfonts) site.